# Multiple Sensors OpenNI usergenerators

Tags: kinect, multiple-instances, openni, asus-xtion

I am working on a project which combines the data of two Asus Xtion (Primesense Sensor device similar to the Kinect)
I am working with OpenNI 1.5.4.0 SDK.

At the moment I have managed to get the depthmap from both devices and showing them simultaneously. However, when I try to add userGenerators I get AccesViolation Exceptions.

My question is: is it possible to define two usergenerators? or is this not possible with this version of OpenNI?